# Powershell FTP - "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable

Tags: powershell, ftp

I am trying to copy a single file to an FTP server.  I found this code online, but cannot get it to work.  I get the following error message:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file
no access)."
At C:\bin\Put-FTP.ps1:22 char:1
+ $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Any idea why this may be occuring? I've checked the destination FTP server and this user has full access to write, read, delete and list contents.

Thanks!

```
$File = "C:\bin\emp1.xlsx"
$ftp = "ftp://user:password@ftp.server.com/User/emp1.xlsx"
"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)
```

Comment: Checked the ftp server to see if the user has rights to upload files? Just because the user account can do something in the target directory doesn't mean the ftp server will allow it.

Comment: try $ftp = "ftp://user:password@ftp.server.com"

Comment: What line of code is at: C:\bin\Put-FTP.ps1:22 char:1 ??

Comment: Excellent points. I think it may be due to a permission issue. I setup a test FTP server locally and it worked.

Comment: It looks like I may need to use my email address as the username.  Do I need to escape the @ sign?  So it would be "ftp://me@domain.com:password@ftp.server.com/User/emp1.xlsx"